# Can I install and run SQL Server locally to develop legally for free?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm developing a database-driven web application. I'm not always connected to the network so I'd like to setup a development environment on my laptop with a SQL Server database. The database won't be hit hard or anything, I just mainly need it so I can make sure my queries are setup correctly for my web pages.

I'm running Windows 7 locally. The actual database production environment is running SQL Server 2000. The web application is being built on Coldfusion8.

Comment: You do realize how obsolete SQL Server 2000 is?

Comment: You do realize how hard it is to get enterprise admins to upgrade?

Comment: You guys are preaching to the choir here.  There are talks about migrating to Oracle but until those details are officially decided upon, we have to work with what we have.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Visit [SQL Server Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) and download the Express edition

Comment: Is this evaluation software or non-expiring?  The download makes references to "evaluation."

Comment: This is non-expiring. Don't worry about anything, just download and enjoy.

Comment: Here's the direct link http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Downloading and installing now.  I'll update again after install and a reboot.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  For the CF developers out there, you will need to enable the TCP connections in order to setup the CF DSNs.  When you setup the CF DSN, you will more than likely get an erorr.  Google this erorr and you'll get a ton of links documenting what you need to update.  Cake!

Comment: I think there are some sql server packages that are not including sql server, just included mssm. the link was a great help to get the full pack, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Express with Management Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650).

If you want to run SQL Server 2000, [find an old copy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000050AVL) of SQL Server 2000 Developer Edition.

Comment: Just keep a note on the new features introduced/changed after SQL2000.
Express is free to use in commercial products.

Comment: @RedFilter this answer is alo correct but I can only "mark" one answer as correct.  I did increase the correct count.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install the full version of MSSQL Server on your computer for development purposes, but you can install MSSQL Server Express for this purpose.

Comment: Why not?  It installs just fine.

Comment: Ok, you "can install"; but you are not allowed as long as you have not bought a license;)

Answer (score 1):

Also, the developer edition for about $50 - this has all the features of the enterprise edition and is well worth the money.

Note that it should only be used for development and is not to be used in a production environment.

Comment: @Jimbo - Developer is all that is needed.  We have a true server for the prod environment.  I'll check out that as well as MSDN.

Comment: @Jimbo - would Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Desktop Engine (MSDE 2000) also work?  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22661

Comment: @dlackey - I think Server 2000 Desktop Engine is the older version of express - not sure if it works on Windows 7 or if it is still supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @Jimbo Based on what I read, I believe you are right.  The link under the answer I selected posted by Michael9000 points directly to the software that I ended up installing and it worked perfectly.  I can now go to Starbucks and code if I want - well, someplace w/o a wifi/vpn connection.  ;)